# Which is most appropriate? "Only do this with {management/management's/managemental} approval."

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, management

Which is most appropriate? "Only do this with {management/management's/managemental} approval."

I get that the word "management" can be singular or plural.  But, can it also be both possessive and plural at the same time, or is the "'s" required when used like this?  Or... is it more appropriate to add the "mental?"

Comment: Idiomatically native speakers would usually go for your first choice there - ***management*** as a "noun adjunct" usage (cf *worker participation, shop assistant, car radio,* etc.).

Comment: *Management and management’s approval* are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the three, *management approval* seems to be the [most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=management%20approval%2C%20management%27s%20approval%2C%20managemental%20approval&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmanagement%20approval%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmanagement%20%27s%20approval%3B%2Cc0), and *managemental approval* extremely uncommon (if used at all).